# How to use functions without having to include libraries in C++

Tags: c++, include

I am having an assignment in which I am not allowed to *include* any other libraries besides the ones that are available. However, I think I really need to use a function that is stored in this particular library.

So, my question is: is there anyway you can use a function in a library without having to *#include* it?

Comment: You don't `#include` a library. You include headers, and link libraries.

Comment: Why would you like to avoid including headers? Headers are good for you - they give you an interface of classes and methods. There is no rational reason to avoid includes...

Comment: I have an assignment which does not allow adding any other #include<> (than the ones given).

Comment: @MSalters I must admit I really don't know how the #include works and what it does for sure. I'd appreciate it very much if you can explain it in more details

Answer (score 3):

Well I'm not sure why you would want to do that, but here is how you'd do it:

Say you want to use a function *foo* from the library that looks as follows:

```
int foo()
{
    return 1;
}
```

In your code where you want to use the function, you need to write the following:

```
extern int foo();
```

and then you can use this foo function as you like, and link it when doing linking.

This works because header files are just needed for compilation to work not for linking, and by using this extern you're manually doing the work that the header did for you

This becomes harder however, if there are classes in the header file, you'll probably end up having to redeclare the whole class as done in the header file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read your answer, however, I still do not know what I need to do. Can you also give me an example of how to use cout this way (not using #include<iostream>).

Comment: Well I can't seem to figure out a way to do it because we need the ostream type to be defined somewhere, without that it wouldn't work
What do you want to do exactly? Maybe there is some other way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks. It's just I have an assignment in which I cannot add in any other #include<> (other than the given ones). However, I have solved it using another way! It's fine now. But it's interesting knowing that it is impossible to use the cout without having #included<iostream>

Comment: What's that assignment? Seems interesting